# even using error_handler got uncaught x3::expectation_failure

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

As I try to rewrite my Spirit X3 grammar, I put some rules (e.g. `char_ > ':' > int_ > '#'`) into a parser class like this one shown here:

```cpp
    struct item_parser : x3::parser<item_parser> {
        using attribute_type = ast::item_type;

        template <typename IteratorT, typename ContextT>
        bool parse(IteratorT& first, IteratorT const& last, ContextT const& ctx, x3::unused_type,
                attribute_type& attribute) const
        {
            skip_over(first, last, ctx);

            auto const grammar_def = x3::lexeme[ x3::char_ > ':' > x3::int_  > '#' ];
            auto const grammar = grammar_def.on_error(
                [this](auto&f, auto l, auto const& e, auto const& ctx){
                    return recover_error(f, l, e, ctx); }
            );
            auto const parse_ok = x3::parse(first, last, grammar, attribute);
            return parse_ok;
        }

        auto recover_error(auto&f, auto l, auto const& e, auto const&) const {
            std::cout << "item_parser::recover_error: " << e.which() << '\n';
            std::cout << "+++ error_handler in: " << excerpt(f, l) << "\n";
            if (auto semicolon = find(f, l, ';'); semicolon == l) {
                return x3::error_handler_result::fail;
            } else {  // move iter behind ';'
                f = semicolon + 1;
                std::cout << "+++ error_handler out: " << excerpt(f, l) << "\n";
                return x3::error_handler_result::accept;
            }
        }
    };
```

(https://godbolt.org/z/MhjYWbE6x) - which works with good input:

```cpp
    std::string const input = R"(
    X := a:42#;
    X := b:66#;
    X := c:4711#;
)";
```

as expected. If I change one line in the input to e.g. `X := b66#;` (note the missing colon `:` inside the literal) it recovers from parser error as expected, but "failed finally" at the end (https://godbolt.org/z/3zabbsWsP).

Input

```cpp
    std::string const input = R"(
    X := a:42#;
    X := b66#;
    X := c:4711#;
)";
```

with output:

```
item_parser::recover_error: ':'
+++ error_handler in: 'b66#;
    X := c:4711#;
'
+++ error_handler out: '
    X := c:4711#;
'
failure
```

For the return of `parse()` (aka `parse_ok`) I expected true since it's never returned `x3::error_handler_result::fail`. Nevertheless, I use an error counter in real.

If I further change the outer rule `item_assign` to `x3::eps > "X" > ":=" > item > ';'` the program is terminated (uncaught expectation_failure) which I haven't expected since it's guarded with an error_handler (tag), see https://godbolt.org/z/dGcYfbG3r

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::spirit::x3::expectation_failure<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >'
  what():  boost::spirit::x3::expectation_failure
```

Maybe I don't see my fault ... or I trigger a bug? Note, that I'm using rule's `on_error()` which mentioned at https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/657 . Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to make up your mind. You're duplicating the error handling code (inconsistently), using a function object as the rule tag (`error_handler`), (but `operator()` is completely ignored there), complicating things because you are using the same tag on different rules.

Then you're **also** using the undocumented interface `parser.on_error(f)` - but it's probably undocumented for a reason. Finally, you're mixing that - for no apparent reason - with a custom parser, which you both want to pre-skip *and* behave as a lexeme.

Oh, and you're dragging in `position_tagged`, `annotate_on_success` and `error_reporting`, none of which you are actually using.

I'd [simplify all the way](https://godbolt.org/z/r57sGYoo6). When you do, you may find that the real reason your stuff doesn't work as expected, is that you're telling the rule to accept result as-if success (`error_handler_result::accept`) but after a successful result `';'` is required. Since you position the cursor *after* the semicolon, that's going to fail:

```
 ========= "
    X := a:42#;
    X := b66#;
    X := c:4711#;
" =====
<grammar>
  <try>\n    X := a:42#;\n   </try>
  <item_assign>
    <try>\n    X := a:42#;\n   </try>
    <item>
      <try> a:42#;\n    X := b66</try>
      <success>;\n    X := b66#;\n   </success>
      <attributes>[a, 42]</attributes>
    </item>
    <success>\n    X := b66#;\n    </success>
    <attributes>[a, 42]</attributes>
  </item_assign>
  <item_assign>
    <try>\n    X := b66#;\n    </try>
    <item>
      <try> b66#;\n    X := c:47</try>
+++ error_handler expected: ':'
+++ error_handler in: '66#;
    X := c'
+++ error_handler out: '
    X := c:471'
      <success>\n    X := c:4711#;\n</success>
      <attributes>[b, 0]</attributes>
    </item>
    <fail/>
  </item_assign>
  <fail/>
</grammar>
failure
```

Simply put the error-handler on the `item_assign` rule - the one that you know how to recover for:

```
struct item_assign_tag : error_handler {};

auto const item
    = x3::lexeme[x3::char_ > ':' > x3::int_ > '#'];
auto const item_assign                                         //
    = x3::rule<item_assign_tag, ast::item_type>{"item_assign"} //
    = x3::eps >> "X" >> ":=" >> item >> ';';
auto const grammar                                          //
    = x3::skip(x3::space)[*item_assign >> x3::eoi];
```

Now the output becomes: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4KE3Y5cb4)**

```
<item_assign>
  <try>X := a:42#;\n        </try>
  <success>\n                X :</success>
  <attributes>[a, 42]</attributes>
</item_assign>
<item_assign>
  <try>\n                X :</try>
+++ error_handler expected: ':'
+++ error_handler in: '66#;
               '
+++ error_handler out: '
                X :'
  <success>\n                X :</success>
  <attributes>[b, 0]</attributes>
</item_assign>
<item_assign>
  <try>\n                X :</try>
  <success>\n            </success>
  <attributes>[c, 4711]</attributes>
</item_assign>
<item_assign>
  <try>\n            </try>
  <fail/>
</item_assign>
 - a:42
 - b:0
 - c:4711
```

Now, in my opinion it would be better if `b:0` wasn't in the output, so perhaps use `retry` instead of `accept`: [Live On CE](https://godbolt.org/z/of9KbrYEd):

```
+++ error_handler expected: ':'
+++ error_handler in: '66#;
        X := c:'
+++ error_handler out: '
        X := c:4711'
 - a:42
 - c:4711
```

Comment: If you want to go with `accept` behaviour, the logic can be simplified a lot. With the undocumented `on_error` wrapping it can all be down to 37 lines of code: https://godbolt.org/z/PW4GaT1fv

Comment: Just thought of ways to make it more reusable/elegant: https://godbolt.org/z/xTTjTKech

Comment: (Even more general and better naming https://godbolt.org/z/vsGPaz1Tc)

Comment: First, thank you for your analyses, despite efforts I have then overlooked some things. The naming is much better now! The source is the attempt of a simplification from a clearly more complex problem - therefore also the parser class with expectation points and handling within this class. I had previously used a parser that was in a simple x3::rule with error_handler - which was a clunky one IMO. Hence the idea to delegate error handling to the class.

Comment: However, I obviously lack background knowledge of the implementation concepts/ideas of X3, as you noted in the first two paragraphs. From the first one I conclude that the tag names of the rules must or should always be different. My idea was that the same error recovery strategy can be used for different rules. That the `operator()` was completely ignored was not intended and I was not aware of it. From the second paragraph I conclude that pre-skip and lexeme duplicate in the application. What they do individually is (I think) clear.

Comment: You wrote in individual SO articles e.g. on semantics action and others and are explicitly addressed. Maybe I was not attentive, but I would be glad if you could explain the concepts (I spontaneously think of your answers regarding `parse()` and `x3::skip[]` and `parse_phrase()`). Thanks a lot!